# ı want to turn bottom edges not perfect line, I want it to come down like a bow how can ı do that?

Tags: edit-mode, edges

blender game boy prototype how can ı make it like u shape   [image]

[image: gameboycolor]

Comment: Hello do you have a picture of what you want or could you draw the shape on the image?

Comment: yes ı can add now,

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to see the mesh by transparency,create a loopcut with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, add some edges with the middle mouse button, <kbd>O</kbd> to enable the *Proportional Editing* option, pull the bottom vertices:

[image]

Comment: +1 but I guess _very_ strictly speaking, the bevel / inset should come after the deformation?  (My wrist is available to be slapped.)

Comment: Yes ideally it should come as early as possible but the OP didn't say anything about his current topology, maybe he should share his file